# Razor "cshtml.g.cs" files not being generated

Tags: razor, .net-core

I created a brand new .net core 2.2 web application project, but I get this error when building:

[image]

I already reinstalled VS 2019 (16.3.10) and the .Net Core SDKs. Same project builds fine on other machines. Seems like razor has some global configuration for generating these `cshtml.g.cs` files, but reinstalling VS was not enough to fix it, these files are not being generated inside `obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Views` folder.

What is the possible reason for this?

Comment: did you try deleting ``bin``, ``obj`` and ``.vs`` folders?

Comment: @PiotrŁazarczyk yep. I even deleted whole projects, cloned again from remote repo and tried building. It works on other machines, but not on mine. I screwed something :( even creating a new project will give me the same error.

Comment: There's a VS cache in ``%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\``, maybe it's not cleaned on uninstall. Also if you have resharper or any other extension try disabling it

Comment: @PiotrŁazarczyk I uninstalled VS and SDKs again, then removed the folder you mentioned and also removed the `dotnet` folder from `C:\Program Files`, then I installed VS 2019 again and now it works. I'm raising an issue in aspnetcore github with all these details, and I'll also attach the folders I deleted. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Raised an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17554